# Twilio: Verify Auth Token & Account SID

Tags: php, twilio

I am developing a script where users can insert their Twilio Account SID & Auth Token (Basically a username pass combo). These credentials are used when sending SMS messages through Twilio REST API. If the credentials are incorrect I get a fatal error (which is bad..).

If the users server has `CURL` or `file_get_contents` enabled I can make a request for that users account (`curl_init('https://' . $accountsid . ':' . $authtoken . '@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts');)` and verify the credentials based on the `http` response code.

However, the problem is not all servers have `curl` or `file_get_contents` enabled. So if the user inputs incorrect Account SID and/or Auth Token they will get a fatal error when trying to send the message.

Obviously you cannot catch and disable a `fatal error`, so any ideas how I could verify account credentials without using `curl` or `file_get_contents`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's stream wrappers - http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php - will allow you to make HTTP requests. In your case, you could use the Account Sid and Auth Token to make a request for something like account information. If you get back the information, you expect, you're done. If not, you handle appropriately.

Regardless, you might be able to simplify the flow a bit.. we have a tool called Twilio Connect which is *like* OAuth in that they don't provide you credentials, they simply authorize you to use their account. The AccountSid/AuthToken are never shared.

Here are some docs on it: http://www.twilio.com/docs/connect

(Disclosure: Twilio employee here.)

Comment: This is a good solution. It will be offered as a script and not a hosted solution so twilio connect wouldn't be suitable. Just need to catch a fatal error before it occurs (ie: make sure credentials are valid). Thanks for the info.

Comment: now  the twilio android samples are crashing with shouting that "**X-Twilio-Error: 31203 No valid account**" ,could expailn it please ?.